# Quilljs, how to wrap selected text in a div?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I would like to wrap selected text in a div in Quilljs using custom buttons. I can then give the div a padding and background so that I can highlight certain areas in the text.

So in this image the selected text must be wrapped, but all elements must be preserved.

[image: Selected text must be wrapped]

I have tried using Block, Inline and Embed. These were the results:

- Block replaces the tag of each element. For example all `<p>` are replaced by `<div>`.
- Inline adds a tag to each element. So a `<div>` is entered within the `<p>`.
- Embed did something similar to Inline.

Also I tried to recreate the code-block functionality but this one removes all elements and makes it plain text.

Any tips would be much appreciated!